# Leaking Fuel Injector Seal

Tags: fuel-system, seal, vacuum

I recently had to remove the fuel injectors and fuel rail to clean out the EGR ports on my Honda Accord.  The EGR port was all clogged up with carbon build up.  I replaced all the old o-rings, cushion rings and injector seals with new ones.  One of the injector seals isn't sealing properly.

- I tried just using clean oil to get them to seal, that didn't work.
- Then I tried silicone gasket maker around the injector seals and that worked less than the oil.

I saw a youtube video where someone used silicone spray.  It looks part of the metal on the engine where this injector goes in isn't quite even at one part.  What's the best way to get this thing to seal up?  The vacuum leak from this is causing my idle to go way up (1.5 - 2k rpms) it gets worse after using the brakes.

***Is there something out there that would work better?***

I've thought of using heavier weight engine oil or putting a washer in front of the cushion so that there will be more pressure on the injector seal.

**Here's a picture of a similar fuel injector.  My model doesn't have insulators though.**

[image]

Comment: You can register your account.  If you don't our access will be given by cookies and will be tied to the web browser your using.  If you create an account you can login with the mobile client or roam from computer to computer.

Comment: btw, good question

Comment: You replaced the seals with new ones ant they leak air? Even when you use silicone gasket around it?

Comment: Are you positive that this is the source of the vacuum leak and not something related to the EGR hose? Could you confirm by spraying carb cleaner around the suspect injector seal and listening for a change in idle rpm? Thanks!

Comment: OP is unregistered, not confident they will respond to the questions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the injector seal.  I took the seals off and saw that one of them was still completely smooth, while the other three had started to develop a circular indentation where they press against the intake manifold.  I could also see a darker spot on the intake manifold where it looked like air was getting in.  I'd check now but the car overheated yesterday and now it won't start.  One of the radiator hoses came off.  I drove it for 10 minutes anyways because I didn't want to be stuck on the interstate.  I know I should have gotten it towed, the engines probably messed up now.

Answer (score 1):

The injector seal is most likely torn. I typically see this when the seal is installed dry.

Get a new seal and reinstall it with some type of lube like Vaseline or silicone spray so the rubber doesn't stick and tear when being pushed into place.

Oil or silicone gasket maker applied after the fact isn't going to work - The o-ring should seal on its own as was designed by the manufacturer.